# MLE of a parameter that is common amongst two separate pdf's

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Say $\mathbf X_{1}$,$\mathbf X_{2}$ ,...,$\mathbf X_{5} $ denote a random sample of 5 observations from the following distributions;

$\mathbf X_{1}$, $\mathbf X_{2} $ ,$\mathbf X_{3}$ are from a gamma distribution with pdf  $\frac{\lambda^5x^4e^{-\lambda x}}{24}$

$\mathbf X_{4} $, $\mathbf X_{5} $ are from an exponential distribution with pdf $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$

I am asked to find the MLE of $\lambda$

I know how to find the MLE of observations from a single probability distribution

I would love some help transforming these distributions so that I can apply the usual process of MLE to a single distribution.

Edit:
Some thoughts so far
$\frac{\lambda^5x^4e^{-\lambda x}}{24}$ is simply $\Gamma$(5,$\lambda$) and $\Gamma$ distribution of (n,$\lambda$) is defined as the sum of n exponential with paramater $\lambda$. Therefore we are dealing with 3 observations of the sum of 5 exponentials with parameter $\lambda$ and 2 observations of a exponential parameter $\lambda$.

Not really sure what to do from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming these random variables are independent (otherwise you need to provide more information) you can write the joint probability distribution:

$$p(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5 | \lambda ) = \prod_i p_i(x_i |\lambda )$$

where $p_1=p_2=p_3$, the pdf of your gamma, and $p_4=p_5$ the pdf of the exponential.

Going on from there, you should be able to compute the MLE.